Nothing commited to database when adding new row in DataGridView with Entity Framework Core
Just starting with EF Core 8 & Winforms.
I bind a list to a data grid view and all edits are committed to the database as expected.
The only issue I have is adding a new row. I figured out I can't do that with List<>, but seems working with BindingList<>.
However in this case, only changes made to existing rows are committed to the database. The new row is not being saved.
Can someone please advise what I'm doing wrong?
List <Product> p_list = context.Products
                               .Where (p => p.Price > 5)
                               .OrderBy (p=> p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Id)
                               .ToList();

var p_list_binding = new BindingList<Product> (p_list);            

// this doesn't allow adding a new row
// dataGridView1.DataSource = p_list;  

dataGridView1.DataSource = p_list_binding;  

** EDIT **
Below screen shows case when using p_list as DataSource. I dont have this err when using p_list_buinding.


If all you did was add the new Product object to the BindingList then that's why. That doesn't add the new item to your DbContext, so there's nothing to save to the database. The existing items are already part of the DbContext, so that's why edits are saved.

OK so what would be best approach here? should I manually loop via BindingList, found newly added records and execute context.Add (product) ?

You can do it as the item is created or add all the new ones before saving.

BTW, I don't really understand how the screenshot pertains to your issue. You say that you can add an item using a BindingList but the error message displayed indicates otherwise. If that error message was for the List then it's irrelevant to the issue and should not be part of the question.

You're supposed to add items to the DbContext, eg : context.Add(new Product(...))

First: use context.Products.Local.ToBindingList(). Then see if this UI error is fixed. Then make sure you have SaveChanges somewhere.

I rolled back your latest revision. Please don't change the original question. The new question you wanted to ask was drowned in the noise of previous questions and edits and the title didn't reflect it. Always ask a new question in such cases.

Thanks @GertArnold ! This is what I was looking for!

Below resolved my problem.
Many thanks @Gert Arnold!
context.Products.Local.ToBindingList()

